# DBT select Big Query table from different Google Project

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I am using DBT to read and write tables in Big Query, all running in my Google project X.

I have one table which I want to read in from a different Google project Y and put in a DBT model (which will then be saved as a table in project X).

Is it possible to do? And if yes, where do I define the different project in `FROM {{ source('dataset_project_y', 'table_to_read')}}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, you need to declare the source in a source.yml file.

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/using-sources#declaring-a-source

for example, create a source_y.yml

```
sources:
  - name: dataset_project_y
    schema: dataset_y
    database: 'project_y'
    tables:

      - name: table_to_read
        identifier: table_to_read
```

after that,
you could refer to source `table_to_read` in any dbt model, select from it in any of the dbt models' SQL satements.

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/using-sources#selecting-from-a-source

For example, to use `table_to_read` in dbt_model_x.sql

```
{{
  config(
    materialized = "view",
  )
}}

SELECT * FROM {{ source('dataset_project_y', 'table_to_read')}}
```